# How can I Scan an index in reverse in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am currently using DynamoDB and having a problem scanning. I am able to get paged results in forward order by using the ExclusiveStartKey. However, regardless of whether I set `ScanIndexForward` true or false, I get results in forward order from my scan operation. How can i get results in reverse order from a `Scan` in DynamoDB?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Which API are you using to access DynamoDB?  Most would not let you specify `ScanIndexForward` for a Scan operation.  Are you directly making web service calls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ScanIndexForward` is the correct way to get items in descending order by the range key of the table or index you are *querying*.  From the [AWS API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

> A value that specifies ascending (true) or descending (false)
>   traversal of the index. DynamoDB returns results reflecting the
>   requested order determined by the range key. If the data type is
>   Number, the results are returned in numeric order. For type String,
>   the results are returned in order of ASCII character code values. For
>   type Binary, DynamoDB treats each byte of the binary data as unsigned
>   when it compares binary values.

Based on the [docs for Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), I conclude that **there is no way to *Scan* in reverse**.  However, I would say that you are not using DynamoDB correctly if you need to do that.  When designing a schema for a database like DyanmoDB you should plan the schema based on your expected queries to ensure that almost all application queries have a good index.  Scans are meant more for sys admin operations or for feeding into MapReduce or analytics. "A Scan operation always scans the entire table, then filters out values to provide the desired result, essentially adding the extra step of removing data from the result set." ([Query and Scan Performance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)) That can lead to [performance problems and other issues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScanGuidelines.html).

Using DynamoDB is fundamentally different from working with a traditional relational database and requires a big change in the way you think about using it.  You need to decide whether DynamoDB's advantages of availability in storage and performance, reliability and availability are worth accepting its limitations.

Comment: yes you are right but ScanIndexForward is work for Query not with Scan.And with Query we can set filter only on HASH key and Range key not on others fields. Totally fed up with DynamoDB.

Comment: You can use query filter on attributes/fields other than H/R key. http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/improved-queries-and-updates-for-dynamodb/

Comment: To clarify the comments.  The Query operation  must take and works on the hash and range key criteria only.  There is an optional query filter that can filter on additional fields.  However, the Query operation is still reading every item matching the hash and range key criteria. It is only returning rows matching the filter. Ideally, the hash and range key condition should be as narrow as possible to avoid reading too many rows.

Comment: @BharatBhushan , What did you do to solve this issue?
Would you like to explain?

Comment: I don't agree with your comment about not using not using DynamoDB correctly if you need to do that. I want to create a secondary index on a date attribute and return items with the most recent date (largest value first). How is this as misuse?

Answer (score 7):

As of now the dynamoDB scan cannot return you sorted results.

You need to use a query with a new global secondary index (GSI) with a hashkey and range field. The trick is to use a hashkey which is assigned the same value for all data in your table.

I recommend making a new field for all data and calling it "Status" and set the value to "OK", or something similar.

Then your query to get all the results sorted would look like this:

```
{
    TableName: "YourTable",
    IndexName: "Status-YourRange-index",
    KeyConditions: {
        Status: {
            ComparisonOperator: "EQ", 
            AttributeValueList: [ 
                "OK"
            ]
        }
    },
    ScanIndexForward: false
}
```

The docs for how to write GSI queries are found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Querying

Comment: so there will be one index key, haven't it lead to hot spots? Maybe better to use something started from same prefix and use BEGINS_WITH instead of EQ?

Comment: You want to try that again?  Using a same throughout he table value for a GSI hash key is completely useless.  Remember that you don't to supply both any more than you needed to supply both when constructing the table.  You could have just a hash_key of what you really wanted.  Or use a concatenated field as the hash key.  All kinds of ugly tricks to get dynamodb to do reasonable things.