# DynamoDB order in descending based on sort key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Currently, I'm using Spring boot with DynamoDB and using DynamoDBMapper for all DB operation. Right now it's sorting in ascending order based on sort key(field name `id`). How can I sort in descending order based on sort key value?

Current code :

```
@Override
public PageImpl<Order> getCustomerOrders(Pageable pageable) {

    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();


    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();


    DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();
    List<String> exp = new ArrayList<>();


    // filters

    if (!exp.isEmpty())
        scanExpression
                .withFilterExpression(String.join(" AND ", exp)).withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);


    PaginatedScanList<Order> scan = mapper.scan(Order.class, scanExpression);




    int start = (int) pageable.getOffset();
    int size = scan.size();
    int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > size ? size : (start + pageable.getPageSize());

    if (start < size)
        for (Order o : scan.subList(start, end)) {
            orders.add(o);
        }

    return new PageImpl<Order>(orders, pageable, size);
}
```

After some googling, I found that I need to set `ScanIndexForward` to be `true` but still I'm confused that how can I achieve it with DynamoDBMApper?

Or should I need to use any low-level class like DynamoDB or AmazonDynamoDb?

Comment: AFAIK, ScanIndexForward only works with Query not Scan. Something similar here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250095/how-can-i-scan-an-index-in-reverse-in-dynamodb?rq=1.

Comment: @ydrall : thanks for your quick response .... Will have a look into it.... 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution myself, Thanks to *[@ydrall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4150668/ydrall)* for the hint. As per his comment, `ScanIndexForward` can only be used with query option so I just updated with [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.QueryScanExample.html). I had created [`DynamoDBQueryExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html) object and updated the property using [`setScanIndexForward`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#setScanIndexForward-boolean-) method ( false ).

Full java code :

```
@Override
public PageImpl<Order> getAllProgramOrder(Pageable pageable, OrderFilter filter) {
    List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();


    DynamoDBQueryExpression<Order> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Order>();

    queryExpression.setScanIndexForward(false);


    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(authenticationFacade.getProgramId()));

    queryExpression.withKeyConditionExpression("hashKey = :val1 ")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);

    PaginatedQueryList<Order> scan = mapper.query(Order.class, queryExpression);


    int start = (int) pageable.getOffset();
    int size = scan.size();
    int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > size ? size : (start + pageable.getPageSize());

    if (start < size)
        for (Order o : scan.subList(start, end)) {
            orders.add(o);
        }

    return new PageImpl<Order>(orders, pageable, size);
}
```

Ref : [How can I Scan an index in reverse in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250095/how-can-i-scan-an-index-in-reverse-in-dynamodb?rq=1)