# Is there any way to sort the result of Lambda function of DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am using AWS Lambda to get result from Dynamo DB. The returned result from Lambda is this:

```
Response:
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "name": "unknown",
      "rid": "1589816220971",
      "rtime": "2020-05-18 23:37:12",
      "status": "unsuccessful"
    },
    {
      "name": "acap",
      "rid": "1589816876343",
      "rtime": "2020-05-18 23:48:10",
      "status": "successful"
    },
  ],
  "Count": 2,
  "ScannedCount": 2
}
```

But i wanted the returned result inverted as this because i want the recent result first.

```
Response:
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "name": "acap",
      "rid": "1589816876343",
      "rtime": "2020-05-18 23:48:10",
      "status": "successful"
    },
    {
      "name": "unknown",
      "rid": "1589816220971",
      "rtime": "2020-05-18 23:37:12",
      "status": "unsuccessful"
    },
  ],
  "Count": 2,
  "ScannedCount": 2
}
```

Is there any way of doing that or more better way to return the latest item first from DynamoDB using Lambda?

Comment: Is it a Nodejs lambda, python... ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ORDER results with query or scan in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297326/is-it-possible-to-order-results-with-query-or-scan-in-dynamodb)

Comment: This looks like results from `scan`. You'll have to sort the results locally.

Comment: You might look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250095/how-can-i-scan-an-index-in-reverse-in-dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250095/how-can-i-scan-an-index-in-reverse-in-dynamodb)

Comment: Yes I am using scan @jarmod, can you elaborate on how to sort locally?  And i have tried dege solution but it returns error.

Comment: Every programming language has a native sort feature. You didn’t indicate a programming language, however. Search for sorting a list with your programming language.